# Web Service Worker to add Authorization token to an external api call

Tags: fetch, authorization, service-worker

I have a service worker which intercepts fetch events, and tries to add Authorization token to external API calls. The worker is installed, activated for the following scope: http://localhost:3505/ which is the root of my (development) application. It calls an external API http://localhost:5098/graphql which is serves as my backend. These calls are initiated on client (browser) side.

For me it seems that the fetch event won't intercept these graphql calls, my first think is because it is outside of the scope.

```
const installEvent = () => {
    self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
        event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
        console.log('>> [SW]: service worker installed');
    });
};
installEvent();

const activateEvent = () => {
    self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
        event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()); // Become available to all pages
        console.log('>> [SW]: service worker activated');
    });
};
activateEvent();

const HTTP_ENDPOINT ="http://localhost:5098/graphql";
const token = "<my-bearer-token-comes-here>";

const fetchEvent = () => {
    self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
        if (token && e.request.url == HTTP_ENDPOINT) {
            e.request.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer "+token;
        }
    });
};

fetchEvent();
```

Is it possible to intercept and modify fetch calls to the graphql endpoint? I think it is not - but a question is worth asking.